# How to pass const QString references?

Tags: c++11, parameter-passing, qt5, pass-by-reference, qt5.4

I have several 'tags' and I would like to create a formatted QString out of these tags, for instance with:

```
void createFormattedPlainText(QString & refLine, const QString & v1, const QString & v2, const QString & v3)
{
  refLine.clear();
  refLine.append("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3);
}
```

SO, I would like to call :

```
QString line;
createFormattedPlainText(line, "123", "**", "xxx");
```

but I can't, I removed the const in the signature, otherwise I got:

> Error: no matching function for call to
>   'createFormattedPlainText(QString&, const char [3], const char [2],
>   const char [3])'    createFormattedPlainText(l1, l2, "123", "**",
>   "xxx" );
>   ??
>   ) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a little confusing.  Did the signature we see lead to the error we see?  You said something about removing const, but it's not clear if that led to the posted error message.  Are you saying removing const led to a successful compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using of `arg()` is wrong, there is no another problem, your function signature is valid and correct.

```
void createFormattedPlainText(QString & refLine, const QString & v1, const QString & v2, const QString & v3)
{
  refLine.clear();
  refLine.append("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QString line;
createFormattedPlainText(line, "123", "**", "xxx");
qDebug() << "line = " << line;
//...
```

**Output:**

```
line =  "[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2"
```

Correct version:

```
void createFormattedPlainText(QString & refLine, const QString & v1, const QString & v2, const QString & v3)
{
  refLine.clear();
  refLine.append(QString("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3));//Attention here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QString line;
createFormattedPlainText(line, "123", "**", "xxx");
qDebug() << "line = " << line;
//...
```

**Output:**

```
line =  "[123] :: [**] ++ xxx"
```

From [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg):

> Returns a copy of this string with the lowest numbered place marker
>   replaced by string a, i.e., %1, %2, ..., %99.

In your case `refLine.append("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3);`, you return copy to the nowhere. In my case `refLine.append(QString("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3));` I append to `refLine` fully constructed string which was processed by `arg()`.

P.S. Of course you can do next (with your old code):

```
void createFormattedPlainText(QString & refLine, const QString & v1, const QString & v2, const QString & v3)
{
  refLine.clear();
  //arg() returns copy so just assign this copy to the refLine again
  refLine = refLine.append("[%0] :: [%1] ++ %2").arg(v1, v2, v3);
}
```

But I think that it is terrible code, I wrote this only to show you that `arg()` returns copy.